# ¿ Cómo mostrar una notificación toastr en la parte inferior derecha?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente comando:

```
toastr.success('Cambios efectuados');
```

Pasa que cuando se ejecuta, se muestra en la parte superior derecha, y lo que quiero es que aparezca en la parte de abajo a la derecha, probé con el siguiente comando:

```
toastr.success('Cambios efectuados',{
                "positionClass" = "toast-bottom-rigth"
              });
```

Pero dejó de funcionar y ya no aparece la notificacion, si alguien me puede ayudar, de ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Deberia ser: "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right". Te faltaron los 2 punticos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dejó de funcionar porque la sintaxis es incorrecta, al ser un objeto de configuración debe tener la forma `clave : valor`  separado por dos puntos.

Para añadir la configuración, Dos formas : De forma global, se podría añadir así.

```
toastr.options = {"positionClass": "toast-bottom-right"}
```

También pasar como **tercer** parámetro. el segundo es para el título.

```
toastr.success('Cambios efectuados', 'Titulo',
          { "positionClass" : "toast-bottom-right"}
      );
```

**Ejm.**

```js
toastr.success('Cambios efectuados', 'Titulo',
     {"positionClass" : "toast-bottom-right"}
  );
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
```